# Google calendar incorrect imports DDay multiple-day events

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, icalendar, dday

I'm using a DDay library to create iCal file. Here's an example of one event that I created:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//MyProduct
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES:Office event
DESCRIPTION:Rudniy\, Kazahstan office has a work day.
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20141207
DTSTAMP:20141230T085900Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20141206
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Work Day in RDN
UID:6418abbe-1904-40c4-8544-e87dd4f4c002
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I import that calendar to Google Calendar, the result event is only on 2014-12-06 and is one day long (instead of two).
Can please somebody tell what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I got it. The END date specifies NON-INCLUSIVE end date for event. So I just should add 1 day to each end date by myself.

Answer (score 0):

When you use end.date and start date properties, you will give date in the format "yyyy-mm-dd". In google calendar, these properties are used to create ONLY "All-day events". Here is [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) for the details on using properties.

Try using the properties end.dateTime(format is 2015-01-03T10:00:00.000-07:00) and start.dateTime properties to create multiple-day events.

Comment: I'm not using an API, just straight importing the calendar from .ics file